# Tie::File - Get 5 lines from a file into an array while removing them from file

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I want to open a file, push 5 lines into an array for later use (or what is left if less than 5) and remove those 5 lines from the file as well.
It does not matter whether I am removing (or pushing) from head or tail of file.

I have used `Tie::File` in the past and am willing to use it, but I cannot figure it out with or without the Tie module.

```
use Tie::File;
my $limit='5';
$DataFile='data.txt';

###open my $f, '<', $DataFile or die;

my @lines;
tie (@lines, 'Tie::File', $DataFile);
$#lines = $limit;

###while( <@lines> ) {

shift @lines if @lines <= $limit;
push (@lines, $_);

###} 

print @lines;
untie @lines;
```

Also tried [`File::ReadBackwards`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards) from an example I found but, I cannot figure out how to get the array of 5.

```
my $pos = do {
my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new($DataFile) or die $!;
#@lines =(<FILE>)[1..$limit];
#$fh->readline() for 1..$limit;

my $log_line = $fh->readline  for 1..$limit;  

print qq~ LogLine $log_line~;

$fh->tell()};
```

All that said, this came close, but no cigar. How do I get the 5 into an array?

```
use File::ReadBackwards;
my $num_lines = 5;
my $pos = do {
my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new($DataFile) or die $!;
$fh->readline() for 1..$num_lines;
$fh->tell()};
truncate($DataFile, $pos)or die $!;
```

I will check each line in the array against a regex later on. They still need to be removed from the file either way.

Comment: It does not matter if removing (then pushing result) from head or tail of file. Any five lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extract the last five lines instead of the first five, then you can use `truncate` instead of writing the entire file. Furthermore, you can use File::ReadBackwards to get those five lines without reading the entire file. That makes the following solution insanely faster than Tie::File for large files (and it will use far less memory):

```
use File::ReadBackwards qw( );

my $num_lines = 5;

my $fh = File::ReadBackwards->new($DataFile)
   or die("Can't open $DataFile: $!\n");

my @extracted_lines;
while ($_ = $fh->readline() && @extracted_lines < $num_lines) {
   push @extracted_lines, $_;
}

truncate($fh->get_handle(), $fh->tell())
   or die("Can't truncate $DataFile: $!\n");
```

Answer (score 2):

This removes the first five lines of the data.txt file, stores them in another array and prints the removed lines on STDOUT:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my $limit = 5;
my $DataFile = 'data.txt';

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $DataFile or die $!;

my @keeps = splice @lines, 0, $limit;
print "$_\n" for @keeps;

untie @lines;
```

Comment: you are an awesome help. Thank you so much for the lesson.

Comment: `splice @lines, -5` is probably faster

Comment: `print shift(@lines), "\n" for 1..$limit`